# Xamarin Application Badge not working on Android Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, badge

I have installed the CrossBadge package to display badges in the application icon but its not working for Android.

```
CrossBadge.Current.SetBadge(number);
```

I am testing in both the simulator (Oreo 8) and physical device running Android pie. The documentation says I can use the line anywhere to set the badge and I am doing it in the constructor of a Xamarin Form but its not appearing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which cross-Badge nuget/package are you using? (I know of 5 different projects that use the namespace "CrossBadge" ;-)

Comment: @SushiHangover https://github.com/alexrainman/Badge

Comment: Did you check whether or not the device is supported in the [setup](https://github.com/alexrainman/Badge#setup) section?